# Google Sign-In or OpenID Connect

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I've been trying to add authentication with Google OpenID Connect on my web app. I started with the OpenID Connect page of the documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect. The steps are clear and I've been able to generate an URL that can authenticate users. Everything seems to work fine. User clicks on link, is directed to Google where she authenticates; she's then redirected to my app's endpoint where it exchanges the `auth_code` for an `access_token`, with the `state` returned matching what she has in `session['openid_state']`, etc.

My problem now is to produce a proper branded button. The Google's OIDC documentation gives hint as to how you can create an authentication url, it does not show you how to make a button. I presume that you have to play with css, html, and some static files. I'd rather avoid this if possible.

In the OIDC document, right from the start it tells you that if you want a "Sign-in with Google" you should use Google Sign-In. What does that mean? Should I use Google Sign-In instead of OIDC and abandon all steps currently described in the OIDC document? Or should I use it as an alternate way to quickly take care of the browser side?

When I look at the Google Sign-In API I don't understand how my OIDC url fits, or where I can instead put params such as the `state`. Google Sign-In is said to be built on top of OIDC, how?

Comment: Hello I have one question about `state` parameter. I've posted a question but it get downvoted. I wanted to know if it should be returned to html after created into server in session variable. If yes when and How can should I return it? Also should I check on client side if both states are equal? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OpenIDConnect is a protocol. It only describes a way to get an id_token but doesn't tell you how you would do the whole lifecycle management. e.g. what happens when a users comes back etc. Of course, If you desire, you can implement it on your own but think about how often you implement TCP/IP protocol when doing development on the internet.

Google sign-in gives you a wrapper library with a simple interface. You just need to call the function and it takes care of the whole interaction with Google and you don't need to care other than passing the config.

Since you make a JS call, you can hold on to the "state" you have and it doesn't need to be passed to Google and back. In a pure protocol it is described and needed when one does a full page redirect to Google so the return url can bring the state back. But you are not doing a full page redirect with the library. I'm sure you saw this [reference doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)